# Power series of $x/(1-ae^{-x})$.

Tags: power-series, bernoulli-numbers, eulerian-numbers

I am looking for a power series expansion for the function $x(1-ae^{-x})^{-1}$ (perhaps for $0<a<1$).

Using the Bernoulli numbers, I can write
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-ae^{-x}} &= \frac{x}{1-e^{-(x -\log(a) )}}\\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n B_n (x-\log(a))^n }{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \frac{B_n (\log(a))^{n-k} x^k  }{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0}  (-1)^n \left( \sum_{m\geq n} \frac{\binom{m}{n} (\log(a))^{m-n} B_m}{m!}   \right) x^n 
\end{align*}
My question is, is there any neater power series expression for the function, in the sense that I don't have to evaluate another infinite sum for each coefficient of $x^n$? Or can we identify the number inside the large bracket of the above?

Comment: The function in the title differs from the one in the question's body

Comment: I made a mistake. The correct one should be the one in the thread.

Comment: You expanded $\frac{{x - \log a}}{{1 - e^{ - (x - \log a)} }}$ and not $\frac{x}{{1 - e^{ - (x - \log a)} }}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is "almost" the generating function of the [Eulerian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number): for $|a|<1$ we have \begin{align*}\frac1{1-ae^{-x}}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-kx)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n a^k\\&=\frac1{1-a}\left(1+a\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{A_n(a)}{(1-a)^n}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\right).\end{align*} It's not hard to see that this actually holds for any $a\neq 1$. To get a "working" limit $a\to 1$ (that would lead to the Bernoulli numbers), multiply the above by $x-\log a$ *(and not just by $x$)*.

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\biggl(\frac{1}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x}}\biggr)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k k!}{(1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x})^{k+1}} B_{n,k}\bigl(a\operatorname{e}^{-x},-a\operatorname{e}^{-x},\dotsc,(-1)^{n-k}a\operatorname{e}^{-x}\bigr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k k!}{(1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x})^{k+1}} (-1)^{n+k} a^k \operatorname{e}^{-kx} B_{n,k}(1,1,\dotsc,1)\\
&= (-1)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^n k!S(n,k)\frac{(a\operatorname{e}^{-x})^k}{(1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x})^{k+1}}\\
&\to(-1)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^n k!S(n,k)\frac{a^k}{(1-a)^{k+1}}, \quad x\to0.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x}}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n} \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n k!S(n,k)\frac{a^k}{(1-a)^{k+1}}\Biggr]\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}.
\end{equation*}

References

1. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
3. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
4. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
5. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 0):

From
\begin{equation}\label{id-gen-new-form1}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}t^n}\biggl(\frac1{\lambda \operatorname{e}^{\alpha t}-1}\biggr)
=(-1)^n\alpha^n\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{(m-1)!S(n+1,m)}\biggl(\frac1{\lambda \operatorname{e}^{\alpha t}-1}\biggr)^m,
\end{equation}
it follows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\biggl(\frac1{a \operatorname{e}^{-x}-1}\biggr)
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{(m-1)!S(n+1,m)}\biggl(\frac1{a\operatorname{e}^{-x}-1}\biggr)^m\\
&\to\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{(m-1)!S(n+1,m)}\biggl(\frac1{a-1}\biggr)^m, \quad x\to0.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we acquire
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{-x}}
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{(m-1)!S(n+1,m)}\biggl(\frac1{a-1}\biggr)^m\Biggr]\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^{m-1}{(m-1)!S(n,m)}\biggl(\frac1{1-a}\biggr)^m\Biggr]\frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!}.
\end{align*}

References

1. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Explicit formulae for computing Euler polynomials in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **272** (2014), 251--257; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2014.05.018.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Some identities and an explicit formula for Bernoulli and Stirling numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **255** (2014), 568--579; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.06.020.
3. C.-F. Wei and B.-N. Guo, *Complete monotonicity of functions connected with the exponential function and derivatives*, Abstr. Appl. Anal. **2014** (2014), Article ID 851213, 5 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1155/2014/851213.
4. A.-M. Xu and Z.-D. Cen, *Some identities involving exponential functions and Stirling numbers and applications*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **260** (2014), 201--207; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.09.077.