# $n$-th derivative of $1/(e^x - 1)$ (related with Bernoulli numbers)

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, taylor-expansion, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

It's well known that

$$\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}\hspace{1cm}\left(\text{or}\hspace{0.5cm} \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\right)$$
where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

I want tho obtain the series of this function but centered in a generic point $x_0=a \neq 0$, that is:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(a)\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}$$

and I wonder if it's possible write the n$-th$ derivative $f^{(n)}(a)$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers $B_n$

Comment: If $a=2\pi i k$, $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, it is easy.

Comment: Very close to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4339617).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is directly related to the [Eulerian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) $A_n(t)$.

This can be shown using the expression for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(t)z^n/n!$; [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) way is to use $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^n t^k=\frac{t A_n(t)}{(1-t)^{n+1}}\qquad(|t|<1)$$ as the definition of $A_n(t)$: assuming $\Re a>0$, for "small enough" $x$ we have $$\frac{1}{e^{a+x}-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k(a+x)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-ka}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-kx)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\frac{e^{-a}A_n(e^{-a})}{(1-e^{-a})^{n+1}},$$ and this implies the following (which extends to $a\notin 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$ by analytic continuation): $$(-1)^n f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{e^{-a}A_n(e^{-a})}{(1-e^{-a})^{n+1}}\color{blue}{\underbrace{{}=\frac{e^a A_n(e^a)}{(e^a-1)^{n+1}}}_{n>0}}.$$

Multiplying the above series by $a+x$ *(not by $x$!)* and taking $a\to 0$, we recover the power series for $x/(e^x-1)$, expressing the Bernoulli numbers as a limit involving the Eulerian polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=y+a$ and $b=e^{-a}$
$$\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\frac{b}{e^y-b}=\frac b{1-b}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac {P_n(b)}{n! \,(1-b)^n}\,y^n$$ where the first polynomials $P_n(b)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(b) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & b+1 \\
 3 & b^2+4 b+1 \\
 4 & b^3+11 b^2+11 b+1 \\
 5 & b^4+26 b^3+66 b^2+26 b+1 \\
 6 & b^5+57 b^4+302 b^3+302 b^2+57 b+1 \\
 7 & b^6+120 b^5+1191 b^4+2416 b^3+1191 b^2+120 b+1 \\
 8 & b^7+247 b^6+4293 b^5+15619 b^4+15619 b^3+4293 b^2+247 b+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The coefficients are related to Eulerian numbers (have a look at $OEIS$ for the different sequences) and try to obtain the general formula for the $P_n(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(\operatorname{e}^x-1)^{k+1}} B_{n,k}(\underbrace{\operatorname{e}^x, \operatorname{e}^x, \dotsc,\operatorname{e}^x}_{n-k+1})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(\operatorname{e}^x-1)^{k+1}} \operatorname{e}^{kx} B_{n,k}(\underbrace{1, 1, \dotsc,1}_{n-k+1})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kk!S(n,k)\frac{\operatorname{e}^{kx}}{(\operatorname{e}^x-1)^{k+1}}\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(j-1)!S(n+1,j)\biggl(\frac1{\operatorname{e}^x-1}\biggr)^j,
\end{align*}
where $B_{n,k}$ stands for the partial Bell polynomials and $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

References

1. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Explicit formulae for computing Euler polynomials in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **272** (2014), 251--257; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2014.05.018.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Some identities and an explicit formula for Bernoulli and Stirling numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **255** (2014), 568--579; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.06.020.
3. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
4. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
5. C.-F. Wei and B.-N. Guo, *Complete monotonicity of functions connected with the exponential function and derivatives*, Abstr. Appl. Anal. **2014** (2014), Article ID 851213, 5 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1155/2014/851213.
6. A.-M. Xu and Z.-D. Cen, *Some identities involving exponential functions and Stirling numbers and applications*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **260** (2014), 201--207; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.09.077.